# Show that a list of polynomials is a basis of the subspace _U_ of $P_3$(R)

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is: Show that 1, $(x - 5)^2$, $(x-5)^3$ is a basis of the subspace *U* of $P_3(R)$ defined by *U* = {*p* ∈ $P_3(R)$ : *p*'(5) = 0}.

My questions/confusions will be distinguished by bolding the font. I've found this question posted on here before, but my specific confusions are different; and the answers weren't totally satisfactory. Any help would be appreciated.

I see that it is a linearly independent set simply because you can't write any of the polynomials in terms of one another; however, the solution is kind of confusing. The solution says that the list's linear independence is clear, so it's easy to tell that *dim U* ≥ 3. **Question 1: Why should it be apparent that the dimension is ≥ 3 at this point? Since we know it's linearly independent, I thought about establishing the span, to see if every element in *U* can be written in terms of them, but I don't know how to establish that *every* vector in *U* can be written as a linear combo of them.**

Further, the solution says that the dim *U* ≤$P_3(R)$ = 4. **However, dim *U* cannot be 4 because otherwise when we extend a basis of *U* to $P_3(R)$, we would get a list with a length of greater than 4**. Can the bolded also be explained/shown to me? Intuitively, it makes sense that the subspace doesn't have all of the vectors in $P_3(R)$, due to the *p*'(5) = 0 restriction. I just can't wrap my head around that statement.

Comment: The set of polynomials is linearly independent because they have different degree: it is impossible to write a polynomial of degree 3 as a linear combination of a polynomial of degree 2 and one of degree 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1: You say that you understand that $\{1, (x-5)^2, (x-5)^3\}$ is a linearly independent set in $U$. By definition, the dimension of $U$ is the size of the largest independent set, so the previous sentence implies that $\dim U \ge 3$.

*[Side note: you don't need to verify it is a spanning set yet; however, if you were able to show it is a spanning set, then $\dim U \le 3$ because the dimension of $U$ is the size of the smallest spanning set.]*

Question 2: You mention that you understand that $U$ does not contain everything in $P_3(\mathbb{R})$, due to the $p'(5)=0$ restriction. Thus, when extending any basis of $U$ to a basis for $P_3(\mathbb{R})$, you must add *at least one element*. This implies $\dim U < \dim P_3(\mathbb{R})=4$.

Comment: If the definition of dimension is the largest independent set, where does the ">" part of the inequality come from in that statement (your response to my first question)?

Comment: @Shocked You have an independent set of size $3$ in $U$, so the largest independent set in $U$ must have size at least $3$.

Comment: I was thinking about it wrong. Thanks.